# More than one Obx in a view

Tags: flutter, get

When handling big views on flutter we can have a whole reactive page. What do you think is the best approach (on a performance point of view)?

```
Obx(
  Column(
    Widget()
    Widget()
    Widget()
    Widget()
    Widget()
  )
)
```

or

```
Column
  Obx(
    Widget
  )
  Obx(
    Widget
  ) 
  Obx(
  Widget
  ) 
  Obx(
    Widget
  ) 
  Obx(
    Widget
  )
```

Comment: If you want the individual widgets to be controlled by get, I believe you **must** use the seconds one, because the .obs variable needs to be used in the direct scope of the Obx.

Answer (score 0):

```
Column(children: [
            Obx(
                Widget
            ),
            Obx(
                Widget
            ),
            Obx(
                Widget
            ),
            Obx(
                Widget
            ),
            Obx(
                Widget
            ),],)
```